# How do I raise a fatal exception ruby?

Tags: ruby

Ruby has a [`fatal`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/fatal.html) exception, but there is no guidance on how to `raise` it and I cannot figure it out. How do I raise a `fatal` exception in Ruby?

Comment: I don't know if this is authoritative, but [tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_exceptions.htm) states, "There is one other exception at this level, Fatal, but the Ruby interpreter only uses this internally." ("this level" being "interrupt", "No memory error" and so on). That would mean you can't raise it, though maybe you could take an action that does. If you could, I don't know if that exception would be reported. There is also the question, "Why raise it?".

Comment: If your program really, really has to stop, `Process.kill('KILL', $$)` to shoot your own process with an unblockable signal. This is usually a really bad idea, mind you, as you probably want to let whatever `ensure` blocks are defined kick in properly.

Comment: @tadman I have never tried that, but the [documentation states](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/f573eee2253f1f6b45cdeeef046e8f6b44f8a215/doc/extension.rdoc#exceptions-and-errors) that `ensure` blocks are to be executed.

Comment: Almost always, raising either StandardError or an exception derived from StandardError is all that is needed to stop your program.  Can you please explain why you want to raise fatal?

Comment: @WayneConrad I was just experimenting with different exception. I wouldn't put this in production code.

Comment: @mudasobwa `rb_bug` is an example of an immediate and complete halt: "Terminates the interpreter immediately. This function should be called under the situation caused by the bug in the interpreter. No exception handling nor ensure execution will be done." A hard `kill` is similar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure you can.

Try this

```
FatalError = ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).find { |klass| klass < Exception && klass.inspect == 'fatal' }
```

And then

```
raise FatalError.new("famous last words")
```

How does this work?

- `fatal` is an internal class without associated top-level constant
- `ObjectSpace.each_object(Class)` enumerates over all classes
- `find { ... }` finds an exception class named "fatal"

---

NB though, despite its name `fatal` is not special, it can be rescued. If you are looking for a way to end your program maybe best call the global `exit` method?

```
begin
  raise FatalError.new
rescue Exception => e
  puts "Not so fatal after all..."
end
```

Comment: While this is a neat trick (+1 for that), it's not something one should use in production code. Either exit directly or raise a normal exception.

Comment: I didn't see your answer, and came here all happy about my `ObjectSpace` trick. 10h too late! Please rename `each` and you'll get my vote ;)

Comment: Also, `fatal` doesn't seem special. It doesn't kill the process, and can still be rescued.

Comment: @holgerjust despite its name `fatal` is not special, it can be rescued. I don't see a reason why someone should ban this from production code.

Comment: Well, why would you go all these length to throw an exception you can't *easily* rescue on its own instead of using your own Exception sub-class? `fatal` is a Ruby-internal Exception and should be used that way. For your own exceptions, you should use your own Exception classes, which almost always should inherit from `StandardError` in order to be rescuable by a simple `rescue`. Just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is, you can, but probably shouldn't. This exception is reserved for Ruby internals. It is effectively hidden to users by being a constant with an all lowercase identifier. (Ruby won't do a constant lookup unless the identifier starts with an uppercase character.)

```
fatal
NameError: undefined local variable or method `fatal' for main:Object
```

The same is true when using `Object#const_get`:

```
Object.const_get(:fatal)
NameError: wrong constant name fatal
```

If this exception class was intended for us to use, then it would be readily available, and not hidden away.

Comment: “Short answer is, you can't.”—strictly speaking, one still can write a native extension, that `#include <ruby.h>` and `rb_fatal("%s", msg);` afterwards.

Comment: You can use `ObjectSpace` to get the class.

Comment: And there seems to be a misunderstanding on how classes relate to constants. It just so happens that each class is assigned to a constant with the same name. But this is just a convention, for example you can do `class A; end; a = A.new; A = 12345; [a.class.name, A] # => ["A", 12345]`